# Alternatives to using $scope.$watch in directive to handle undefined variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope, watch

I'm developing an application using angularjs and I'm also using directives because some UI is re-used across multiple pages. When I have a directive which is dependent on a value from a promise I have to use $scope.$watch and an if condition to check for undefined, because the directive compiles before the promise is completed. Here is an example:

```
myAppModule.directive('topicDropdown', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/shared/dropdown/tmplTopic.html',
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                subjectId: '=',
                setDefault: '=',
                topicId: '='
            },
            controller: [
               '$scope', 'service', function ($scope, service) {

                   $scope.$watch('subjectId', function () {
                       if ($scope.subjectId != undefined)
                           $scope.getTopics();
                   });

                   $scope.getTopics = function () {
                       service.get("section/topics/" + $scope.subjectId).then(function (data) {
                           $scope.listOfTopics = data;
                           if ($scope.setDefault) {
                               $scope.subjectId = $scope.listOfTopics[0].UniqueId;
                           }

                       });
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    });
```

The subjectId will eventually come from a promise but without the $watch I'll get an undefined error because it will fire getTopics without an ID.

```
scope: {
                subjectId: '=',
                setDefault: '=',
                topicId: '='
            },
```

Currently, this code works but I'm having to invoke the digest cycle every time subjectId changes which will loop through everything that scope is watching. I only care when subject ID changes at this point.

I've also seen some suggestions to use ng-if for the template html. Something like this:

```
<div ng-if="subjectId != undefined">
    <topic-dropdown subject-id="subjectId"></topic-dropdown>
</div>
```

With this, I don't have to use $scope.$watch however I'm not sure if this is the best approach either.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem? Are there any directive properties that I could be using which I am unaware of?

Nick

Comment: Why not pass a `subjectIdPromise` to the directive instead? Give it a promise that will resolve to the value you need and it should all work cleanly.

Comment: Why you care about digest loop? Performance issue? If you need to make the http get only when the valued become defined then save the $watch deregistration function return value and call it when done to unregister the watcher.

Comment: @fantarama The reason I care is mostly performance issues and curiosity to see if there is a better way or what the common practise would be. I didn't consider de-registering the $watch.

Comment: @Duncan Wouldn't I have the same problem? If I were to pass through subjectPromise and use subjectPromise.resolvedValue, wouldn't it say undefined when the directive compiles? I feel that directory "compilation" is where I'm getting a bit stuck. An angular controller and a controller within a directive have different life cycles.

Comment: Not if you pass through the subjectId as a promise then in getTopics do `subjectIdPromise.then(function(subjectId) { ... })` to get and use the actual value.

Comment: With angular 1.5 you can define the scope attribute with "<" to avoid bidirectional binding, and if you use the "::" notation on template the template watcher live only while is undefined (then you will have 3 watcher less)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a promise for the subjectId and make `getTopics` wait for it to resolve. It would look something like this:

```
$scope.getTopics = function () {
    $scope.subjectIdPromise.then(function (subjectId) {
        $scope.subjectIdPromise = service.get("section/topics/" + subjectId)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.listOfTopics = data;
            if ($scope.setDefault) {
                return data[0].UniqueId;
            } else { return subjectId; }
        });
    });
};
```

Doing it this way all access to the `subjectId` is done in a `then` success function. If you then want to change the `subjectId` do it by replacing the promise with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using promise patterns,

```
myAppModule.directive('topicDropdown', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/shared/dropdown/tmplTopic.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            subjectId: '=',
            setDefault: '=',
            topicId: '='
        },
        controller: [
           '$scope', 'service', function ($scope, service) {

               $q.when($scope.subjectId).then(
            service.get("section/topics/" + $scope.subjectId).then(function (data) {
                   $scope.listOfTopics = data;
                   if ($scope.setDefault) {
                       $scope.subjectId = $scope.listOfTopics[0].UniqueId;
                   }

               });
            )
        ]
    }
});

OR

myAppModule.directive('topicDropdown', function ($q) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/shared/dropdown/tmplTopic.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            subjectId: '=',
            setDefault: '=',
            topicId: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         $q.when(subjectId).then(
            service.get("section/topics/" + scope.subjectId).then(function (data) {
                   scope.listOfTopics = data;
                   if (scope.setDefault) {
                       scope.subjectId = scope.listOfTopics[0].UniqueId;
                   }

               });
            )
        }
    }
});
```

but I think one way or another you are going to use $watch. Using $watch do not harm anything, its angular way to keep things connected.